# How to check if all the keys of an array are in the expected format

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with multiple keys and I want to be sure they're all in the format I want. For example, if they're all ISO Alpha-2 country codes, I created one function returning true or false to test it.

Basically, I would like to replace this foreach by only one line:

```
$countriesList = ['US', 'FR', 'CA'];
$correct = true;

foreach ($countriesList as $iso2) {
    if (!$this->isIso2($iso2)) {
        $correct = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `array_filter(array_map([$this, 'isIso2'], $contriesList));`

Comment: *"I would like to replace this foreach by only one line"* — why?

Comment: @salathe It's just to clean a bit my controller and to learn something new.

Comment: Your code is currently: 1. Working fine. 2. Readable. 3. Maintainable. If you go and cram it all into one line you're going to lose 2 and 3, and maybe also 1.

Comment: @Sammitch It makes sense, thank you for your advice

Comment: I would too to suggest to stick with the `foreach` approach. Anyway, as a *programming exercise* you can substitute the loop with a single call using `array_walk`. See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* want to replace the `foreach` with a single call you can use **[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)** as follows:

```
$countriesList = ['US', 'FR', 'CA'];
$correct = true;

array_walk( $countriesList, function( $country ) use (&$correct) { $correct = $correct && $this->isIso2( $country ); } );
```

---

The statement `use (&$correct)` lets the inline callback access the `$correct` variable (that otherwise would be out of the callback scope).

---

**Note:**

you don't have a *problem* in your original code.

It's readable, concise and I don't see any evident performace flaw.

I would just add a `break;` to terminate the loop the first time a "false case" is found. There is no reason to keep iterating:

```
if (!$this->isIso2($iso2)) {
    $correct = false;
    break; // <--- EXIT THE LOOP
}
```

In production I would definitely stick with the `foreach` approach.

Anyway as a *programming exercise* the solution at the beginning of my answer reduces the loop at a single call.

`array_walk` iterates over all the items of an array. For each item the inline callback function is invoked with the current item passed as first parameter.